# Windows 10 Reset: Does Remove Everything erase D: too?

Tags: windows-10

So, this feature on Windows seems good, apparently no need to format the computer any more when things start running slowly, but I have a a question about it:

When I go to

> Reset Windows 10

and select

> Remove Everything

What exactly is everything? Will it remove everything under C: or would it also delete from D:?

My guess is that it erases everything on the Windows installation drive, but is there any official MS source saying that? I want to try, but don't want to risk losing all my files on D:

Comment: Did you do any research? This is a [very well documented feature](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12415/windows-10-recovery-options).

Comment: Sorry if that sounded harsh. The bottom line is; backup, backup, backup.

Comment: Charlie- that Microsoft documentation page does not really answer the question. There is a short section about the Remove Everything option which does not mention the drive selection menu that pops up when you click the reset button.

Comment: No, it will erase your Windows drive which is usually C: drive

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://www.asus.com/support/faq/1013064) Asus support page has a step-by-step walk-through of the process. Apparently, there's a screen where it asks if you want to erase just your main drive or all drives. As an extra precaution, I recommend unplugging your D drive(if possible).

Comment: how can one unplug d drive if it's a partition? Please mention external drive in your answer.

Comment: Unless it's a laptop, unplugging a drive is usually not too difficult. You pop open the case, and (carefully) tear out the cable. Sure, it's a pain, but if I were doing something so serious as resetting the system it would still be a good extra precaution. Not absolutely necessary, but a recommendation.